# Design Tracking of Emails sent from SMTP server

Tags: web-services, email, data-structures, smtp

I am trying to design a service to send emails to users. This service is pretty much similar to Amazon SES.

One of the requirement is to keep track of all the emails that this system will be sending. I am confused as how to design this solution so that I can maintain the emails sent with parent user(known at the time of sending email) who sent emails.

If I start dumping all the email related data in relational DB, it will grow exponentially over period of time and will create a lot of problem. Similarly if I store these things in Cassandra it will grow at good speed and create problems.

Need for storing this information:-

1) In future need to know if email was sent to a particular user and when.

2) If the feedback loop creates complaint mail, I will need to map it back to a particular email id(which will be present in complaint email) and parent user who sent it(which will be stored at the time email was sent).

Can someone help me giving pointers as, how to store or create some cache in a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely to grow "exponentially." Seems like it will grow linearly. Regardless, if you need the ability to look up who sent what to whom, then you have no choice but to store it.

What you need to do is estimate how many emails you send per day, and how much data you need to save with each of those emails. Do the math and determine how much data you expect to be generating each day. Then at least you can figure out how large your database will get over time.

You'll also need to consider how you want to index the data. Seems like you'll want to index by email id, at least. You might also want to index by sender, and also possibly by recipient. Those indexes will create additional per-email data storage requirements. How much is something you'll have to determine through analysis.

How much actual disk space this will occupy per email is hard to determine. If the messages are short, you could probably get more than a million emails per gigabyte in a relational database. You could potentially do much better than that if you compress the message data, or apply other techniques that take advantage of similarities in the messages. For example, if you send the exact same message to a thousand recipients, you can store a single copy of the message and just store a reference to that message in the individual email records.

You might also want to consider how long you need to store each message. Do you need to store everything forever, or can you periodically remove all messages that are older than a year (or some other relatively long amount of time)?